# Распечатать файл BMP на принтере Godex RT-230 на ЯП C#

Tags: c#

Моя программа формирует необходимую этикетку (картинку BMP) а затем выводит её на печать. Это работает на самых обыкновенных принтерах. Другое дело RT-230, он просто "плюёт" пустую этикетку. На печать я отправляю так:

```
    void Print()
    {
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
        pd.Print();
    }
    void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@$"{path}" + 
        @"\blank1.bmp");
    Point loc = new Point(0, 0);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);
    }
```

Обычный принтер справляется с печатью. Как это повторить на RT-230?
Может существует спец. библиотека для работы с такими принтерами?

Нашёл информацию о том, что существует некий язык EZPL для подобных принтеров. Этот язык заявлен в доках у производителя. Я скачал программу Go Label, подключил к ней принтер. Добавил текст на этикетку в программе и сбоку она сгенерировала этот самый EZPL таким образом:

^Q20,3
^W30
^H8
^P1
^S3
^AD
^C1
^R0
~Q+0
^O0
^D0
^E12
~R255
^L
Dy2-me-dd
Th:m:s
AD,82,74,1,1,0,0E,тестовая
AD,82,112,1,1,0,0E,печать
AD,82,150,1,1,0,0E,шрифт ПО
E

Затем я использовал такой код на C#:

```
void printEzpl()
{
// Printer IP Address and communication port
string ipAddress = "192.168.1.160";
int port = 9100;

// ZPL Command(s)
string ZPLString =
"^Q20,3" +
"^W30" +
"^H8" +
"^P1" +
"^S3" +
"^AD" +
"^C1" +
"^R0" +
"~Q+0" +
"^O0" +
"^D0" +
"^E12" +
"~R255" +
"^L" +
"Dy2-me-dd" +
"Th:m:s" +
"AD,82,74,1,1,0,0E,тестовая"+
"AD,82,112,1,1,0,0E,печать"+
"AD,82,150,1,1,0,0E,шрифт1"+
"E";

try
{
    // Open connection
    System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
    client.Connect(ipAddress, port);

    // Write ZPL String to connection
    System.IO.StreamWriter writer =
    new System.IO.StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
    writer.Write(ZPLString);
    writer.Flush();

    // Close Connection
    writer.Close();
    client.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Пока это без картинки, просто хочу хотя бы что-то напечатать. При этом программа Go Label этикетку отпечатала, а вот код на C# и не упал и ничего не напечатал.